# Rails: Understanding uniqueness scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably a silly question, but I want to make sure I understand how the "scope" field with the uniqueness model constraint.

I was following along this guide: https://dankim.io/mutual-friendship-rails/ to understand handling "Friends" associations in rails. At one part it talks about making a uniqueness constraint:

`validates :friend, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :user }` (Which goes in the `friendship` model.

So this is saying that the `friend_id` field should never be duplicated with the same `user_id` field right?

Wouldn't this have also worked as:
`validates :user, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :friend }`

Saying a user shouldn't show up more than once with the `user_id` having a duplicated `friend_id`. Or am I mis-understanding how the `scope` works here?

Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming that a user is adding friends which means that the original validations ensures the friend is unique to the user. The other way around would make less sense since the error would be attached to the `user_id` as if the friend was adding a user, but yes the validation would fail in the same fashion either way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Scope is a fancy way of say *allow just one duple (user, friend)*.

If you set an index on your DB (which is necessary to avoid race conditions with uniqueness validation) you'll do exactly the same thing:

```rb
add_index :friendships, [:user_id, :friend_id], unique: true
```

Comment: Can you go into detail on why the index is necessary? Im not that familiar with rails and have only seen indexes used a few times? Why is the model validation not enough?

Answer (score 2):

Difference is in which field is checked, because relation is directional (and to make it non-directional - inverse relationship is created in the article).

In your example - for duplicate records it's the inverse relation that will fail to validate

Also for `uniqueness`-validation it's always useful to have corresponding database unique index (because validation-saving is not atomic)